# Ngx translate with lazy loading in angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, ngx-translate

I tring to use translate the text inside my renderd html 
But only the glitch text appear inside it 
I make translate module inside server module
But only global components like navbar was translated

Any help !?

Answer (score 1):

i fix it my usign custom loader get the translate from asstest by import json

> custom Json loader

```
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";


import { TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";


export class JSONModuleLoader implements TranslateLoader {
TRANSLATIONS: {
    ar: any,
    en: any
}
constructor(TRANSLATIONS: any) {
    this.TRANSLATIONS = TRANSLATIONS
}
getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.TRANSLATIONS[lang]);
}
}
```

> my module factory

```
import { JSONModuleLoader } from './translate/translateLoader';
import { AppTAr, AppTEn } from '../environments/translat';
let TRANSLATIONS = {
  ar: AppTAr,
  en: AppTEn
}
export function createTranslateLoader() {
  return new JSONModuleLoader(TRANSLATIONS);
}
```

and it's work now :"D